# Override Edit All Order Products page w Visual Force using Standard Controllers possible?

Tags: visualforce

We have different record types for Orders and depending on the Record Type the fields populated for Order Products differ.
Since Salesforce does not support RTs for Order Products (as well as Opp/Quote products) I developed visual force page with conditional formatting based on RT for editing Order Products.

However can't figure out a method to override Edit All button with VisualForce page using Standard or List Controller - trying to avoid writing a custom controller.   When I try to use List controller get error that Order Products object is not supported.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: vote up this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000cIGpAAM)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the StandardSetController doesn't support line items (quotes, opportunity, order, etc). You definitely need either a custom controller or use JavaScript remoting (e.g. apex:remoteObjects).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  So I started down the path of using a controller extension.  However Not sure what is going on but when I use my sample page to override the standard Order Item "Edit All " button the view state is not initialized with the Order record.  However if I use the same VF page to override the "Add Product" standard button it initializes the view state data as expected.  I have not done a ton of VF work recently so perhaps I am missing something obvious?